# How to show the object object data presentation returned from the API

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Below is the response from my `API`

```
"attributes": {
"original-data": "{\"name\":\"Foobarz\",\"updated_at\":\"2018-02-27 
08:06:14 UTC\"}",
"new-data": "{\"name\":\"Foobar\",\"updated_at\":\"2018-02-27 
10:55:17 UTC\"}",
"event-name": "update",
"ip-address": "121.58.201.106",
"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 
Safari/537.36",
"created-at": "2018-02-27T10:55:17.477Z",
"updated-at": "2018-02-27T10:55:17.477Z"
},
```

Below is my model hook on my `route.js`

```
model() {
  return this.store.findRecord('audit-trail', 41, {include: 'audit-trailable'});
}
```

When i do `{{model.eventName}}` it show the event-name information which is `update`. However, when i did the `{{model.newData}}` it retrun a `[object Object]`. My question is, how can I display the `new-data` attribute filed value `name` and `updated_at`?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hy there. The best, if you can afford it, is to use https://github.com/lytics/ember-data-model-fragments

and so : models/audit-trial.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import MF from 'ember-data-model-fragments';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    whatever_simple_attr: DS.attr(),
    new_data: Mf.fragment('new-data'),
});
```

with : models/new-data.js

```
import MF from 'ember-data-model-fragments';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default MF.Fragment.extend({
    name: attr(),
    updated_at: attr('date')
});
```

*edit : adding serializers* , again : not really tested, but the idea is here ->

serializers/new-data.js (using underscore.js lib)

> important : I'm using snake_case attributes in my models, maybe your code will be different if you are using lowerCamelCase.

```
import JSONSerializer from 'ember-data/serializers/json';
/* global _ */

export default JSONSerializer.extend({
  normalize(typeClass, hash) {
    _.forEach(hash, (value, key) => {
      hash[key.underscore()] = value;
      // prevent kinda twins (my_key and my-key)
      if (key.underscore() !== key) {
        delete hash[key];
      }
    });
    return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  }
});
```

serializers/audit-trial.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({

  normalize(_, data) {
    data.attributes["new-data"] = JSON.parse(data.attributes["new-data"])
    // maybe this too, with associated model and serializer
    data.attributes["original-data"] = JSON.parse(data.attributes["original-data"])
    return this._super(...arguments);
  },

});
```

Comment: Hi @Nathan thank you for your suggestion and I was amazed by this approach and I really appreciate it. However, my API does not return an array of records for `new_data` but a `string` from API. My goal is if the API return a string how can I separate the information of `name` and `update at` fields.

Comment: I would recommend use a customized serializer which converts the string to a JSON object (along with ember-data-model-fragments) https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/release/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer/methods/serialize?anchor=normalizeResponse

Comment: @Mikelemuel my mistake. As Leon Dmello suggested, you should first use a serializer before using the above solution. Is it clear for you or you need a detailed answer ?

Comment: Hi @NathanGouy I would love to hear a detailed answer and would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Mikelemuel check it out, feel free to ask more details or the why's

Comment: hi @NathanGouy thank you! your approach works too! Thank you for your outstanding efforts!

Comment: @NathanGouyHi, yes it did! You have helped me so much!

Comment: Don't hesitate to pass as answered then ;)
Glad to helped

Answer (score 0):

Ember-data-model-fragments are ok. Or you can use model like:

```
DS.Model.extend({
  originalData: DS.attr("string"),
  newData: DS.attr("string"),
  ...
```

and then use in your component (or controller):

```
originalData = JSON.stringify(model.get("originalData"))
```

in your template:

```
{{originalData}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `{{model.newData.name}}` in your template do things work? Ember Data’s default approach to to any object is to just make it available as you send it from the backend. That means it will have underscored keys (I.e. `model.newData.updated_at`) but should work.